# app crashes after hacking cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview to include crosswalk-lite

Tags: cordova, crosswalk-runtime

I am trying to add crosswalk-lite to my cordova project using cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview. I created a maven repos of https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk-lite/android/canary/10.39.237.1/arm/crosswalk-webview-10.39.237.1-arm.zip on my github page, and modified xwalk.gradle pointing my maven. Building is OK, apk file size also looks as expected.

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/Poordeveloper/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
```

But app crashes with.

```
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2448)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:173)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1392)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5469)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:857)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create webview.
    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl.createEngine(CordovaWebViewImpl.java:82)
    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.makeWebViewEngine(CordovaActivity.java:191)
    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.makeWebView(CordovaActivity.java:187)
    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.init(CordovaActivity.java:135)
    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.loadUrl(CordovaActivity.java:209)
    at com.carriez.carbroker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5226)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1151)
    at com.lbe.security.service.core.client.b.x.callActivityOnCreate(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
    ... 11 more
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl.createEngine(CordovaWebViewImpl.java:80)
    ... 20 more
 Caused by: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Please extend XWalkActivity for shared mode
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
    at org.xwalk.core.XWalkCoreWrapper.initEmbeddedMode(XWalkCoreWrapper.java:112)
    at org.xwalk.core.XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.java:105)
    at org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkCordovaView.setGlobalPrefs(XWalkCordovaView.java:41)
    at org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkCordovaView.<init>(XWalkCordovaView.java:50)
    at org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkWebViewEngine.<init>(XWalkWebViewEngine.java:56)
    ... 23 more
```

Wondering if anyone can help on this.

Comment: I think it is because lite not compatible with cordova >= 4.0. It sucks. Just wondering why the project  does not pay enough attention to lite branch. For me, the lite branch is much more important than the huge main branch. Who wanna use a lib with 20+M?

Comment: Hopefully, Crosswalk Lite 14 comes out ASSP.

Comment: https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk/commits/lite 
Apparently, they're working on a lite version for 15. Just waiting for the official release ...

Comment: The reason it is crashing is because the mainactivity should extend from xwalkactivity where you should implement onwebviewready. The libxwalkcore.so lite edition is compressed and must be decrompressed first. In my situation everything compiles. App starts. But i get a popup saying that the crosswalk library is for the wrong architecture. Dont know yet why it is saying that cause i am using the right one. Once i have solved that i will powt it here.

Comment: I have same problem with android 4.3. My app work on android 5.0 smoothly. App give same errors like above but i don't know how to resolve this. Please help me